# Loading masonry-layout in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

I have an [angular 2](https://angular.io/) project based on [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/). It is using webpack, and it works very well for a lot of imports, even jQuery plugins..

I am trying to get [angular2-masonry](https://github.com/jelgblad/angular2-masonry) to work now, but it depends on the `masonry-layout` package ([npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/masonry-layout) / [github source](https://github.com/desandro/masonry)), which does not play nicely...
The importing (`import * as masonry from 'masonry-layout'`), wont work and is giving the error `Cannot find module 'masonry-layout'.`.

How can I get webpack to see this as a module?

I have tried (only relevant webpack config);

**Setting alias to `masonry.pkgd.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'masonry-layout': 'masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the same error

**Setting alias to `masonry.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'masonry-layout': 'masonry-layout/masonry.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Same error

**Adding a custom loader, and installing `imports-loader` as suggested [here](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/679#issuecomment-78625842)**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /masonry-layout/,
        loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Same error!

Only by combining the first (`'masonry-layout': 'masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js'`) and the last, I am getting another error;

```
ERROR in ./~/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./item in /.../node_modules/masonry-layout/dist
 @ ./~/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js 1351:6-23
```

But only in addition, I am still getting the `Cannot find module 'masonry-layout'.` error.

I am still new to webpack, so I might miss something obvious...

Comment: Have you tried `var Masonry = require('masonry-layout');` as described here https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/679#issuecomment-78625842?

Comment: I tried to change out the lines for loading and initializing in `angular2-masonry` to use require instead, and that seams to work... Thanks for making me try that, I have only seen it, but didn't think it would work.. :) I updated https://github.com/jelgblad/angular2-masonry/issues/5 with info to see if he can include a fix..

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install masonry-layout`. I was having the same issue earlier and I just installed the original masonry package instead of directing angular to solve find it in anglular2-masonry.

Comment: yea.. https://github.com/jelgblad/angular2-masonry/issues/5 got solved a couple of days ago. So it should all works now :) I've been testing as well. Works well